# Ubuntu is my Default OS, how do I install Windows 7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

My default OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I realise now that need to run certain windows software that can not run in the Ubuntu environment. How can I install Windows 7, so that I have a dual boot? I have tried searching for on the web for solutions but most point towards people who already have windows as the default OS and want to install Ubuntu, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1** Open Ubuntu Software Center
[image]
**Step 2** Search For UnetBootin its a program for creating boot-able usb and double click it
[image]
**Step 3** Click install i have clicked install already
[image]
**Step 4** Now search Ubuntu dashboard Unetbootin And Run it
[image]
**Step 5** Dont Slect any distribution or version

**Step 6** Tick mark Disk image Browse to you windows iso

**Step 7** Chose Your usb drive and click ok

Comment: Have you tried this? Has it really worked out for you? and are there any side effects I should expect after this? I am only asking because I wouldn't want to mess up my system after following your instructions?

Comment: No i havent tried this it will only create a bootable usb with windows in it.